# One-loop renormalization of the gauge coupling

Tags: gauge-theory, renormalization, representation-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, yang-mills

Quoting Yuji Tachikawa, chapter 3 of "${\cal N}=2$ Supersymmetric Dynamics for Pedestrians":

> Recall the one-loop renormalization of the gauge coupling in a general Lagrangian field theory $$E\frac{d}{dE} g = -\frac{g^3}{(4\pi)^2}\left[\frac{11}{3}C(adj)-\frac{2}{3}C(R_f)-\frac{1}{3}C(R_s)\right].$$

The exact notation is given in the book. Since there were no references for the calculation, I assume this is a standard fact. How can I derive the beta function for the gauge coupling in a general Lagrangian field theory.

Comment: OP's result is derived in any good textbook on QFT.

Comment: @Qmechanic Do you know of a shorter calculation than [these 25 pages](https://web2.ph.utexas.edu/~vadim/Classes/2019f/qcd-beta.pdf)?

Comment: @J.G. These calculations are always quite tedious/long just due to their nature, so maybe you'll find something shorter but then they probably just skimp on some details...

Comment: @ThomasTappeiner I suspected as much. Hopefully it'll be of some help to the OP. What can probably be made succinct is an explanation of why each $1$-loop contribution to $E\frac{dg}{dE}$ is proportional to $\frac{g^3}{3(4\pi)^2}$.

Comment: @J.G.: I didn't look at your link but that page length sounds reasonable.

Comment: @Qmechanic I thought using background field method with the Wilsonian approach to RG flow is much shorter. Or am I missing any details? In Peskin and Tong it didn't take 25 pages.

Comment: Yes, the background field method is indeed shorter.

Comment: Indeed, it is. See Sec. 8.4 [here](https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/dbs26/AQFT/chap8.pdf).

Comment: @J.G. Thanks for your last comment. That should do the job.